# Remove User from Directory Role using Graph API

Tags: directory, microsoft-graph-api, roles, credentials

I am trying to add and remove users from a directory role (Guest Inviter) based on a user's ID.  My client ID has Directory.AccessAsUserAll  for the Microsoft Graph application.  I am using the ID for the directory role and the ID for the user.  Using an HTTP Client call (verb is DELETE) I use the format suggested by Microsoft and get an "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." error. I can perform other functions successfully

It seems clear to me that I am missing something.  I would think that you still log in with the Client ID and Client Secret then do something with an admin type id and password rather than just create a new token based these credentials (because then why would you link them) similar to impersonation code but I don't know how and cannot seem to find an example of how.

Using HTTPClient 
Verb DELETE

following this pattern
DELETE /directoryRoles/{id}/members/{id}/$ref

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-delete-member?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Using C# creating bearer token (with client id and client secret) then using an HTTPCLient  I call DeleteAsync using a url string based on the recommended pattern.

I see references to needing to pass user credential for a user in an admin role.

I think the issue is the absence of something important.  This is called once the bearer token is obtained using client id and client secret for out tenant.

```
 string delURL = $"{settings.RestUrl.value}{settings.RestVersion.value}/directoryRoles/{settings.GuestInviterRoleObjectID.value}/members/{user.id}/$ref";

                    HttpResponseMessage payload = await client.DeleteAsync(delURL);

                    Task<string> json = payload.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    JObject o = new JObject();

                    if (json.Result.Length > 0)
                    {
                        o = JObject.Parse(json.Result);
                    }
```

I would like to remove the user from the Guest Inviter directory role.  I get however

```
error:  code:"authorization_requestDenied",
messsage: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"  ....
```

Update:  I was following this example  https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau-2

I built a class to contain the properties so after getting my original token using Client ID and Client secret then feeding in what I was told was a global admin credentials and now I get a 401 unauthorized error.

```
string tURL = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{settings.TenantID.value}/oauth2/token";

using (System.Net.WebClient c = new System.Net.WebClient())
                    {
                        c.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {token}";
                        c.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

                        body.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(delegate (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item)
                        {
                            data.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(body) == null ? string.Empty : item.GetValue(body).ToString());
                        });


                        var res = await Task.Run(() => c.UploadValues(tURL, data));

                        Task.WaitAll();

                        if(res != null)
                        {
                           string response =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res);
                        }
                    }

Data object
public class JSONBody
    {

        public string grant_type { get; set; }
        public string client_id { get; set; }
        public string client_secret { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        public JSONBody()
        {
            this.grant_type = "password";
            this.resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
        }

    }
```

I cannot prove or disprove the 401 error because I cannot prove my code works (or doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-delete-member
You’ll need an application with the delegated `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission. The you’ll need an admin to login to that application (with the correct permissions).

The application credentials (or client credentials flow) is unsupported, by design.

This could result in privilege elevation, if some admin would create an application with these permissions. If that admin would then be removed from the admin role he would be able to use his application to make himself admin again

Comment: I do have the remove code there but I am attempting to get elevated permissions to do so using the https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT ID}/oauth2/token call with the credentials in the body.  The user id and password seem valid but I am getting the below error message                                                 "error": "invalid_grant",    "error_description": "AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: \r\nCorrelation ID: Timestamp: 2019-06-24 18:59:18Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50126

Comment: You application would need the `user_impersonation` privilege. And you would need to access it at least once in the browser where you would grant the permissions.